# Pass parameter as well as binary file data to web api controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have an ajax call which works fine right now to pass just the binary data for a file upload:

```
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("file0", file);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/api/breeze/uploadImage",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (res) {
                    //do something with our response
                }
            });


<HttpPost> _
Public Function uploadImage() As HttpResponseMessage

    ...
    do stuff with file, save to disk
    ...

    Return result
End Function
```

As I say, all works fine.  However I also want to now pass in a couple of parameters as well as the binary data (e.g. an upload folder name) but I have no idea how to do this.  Do I have to create a custom json object and muck about serializing it or am I missing an easier way to pass parameters in the ajax request?

Comment: like  data.append("name", file.name); ?

Comment: Not really. As the contenttype is false, the ajax call posts the data as multipart/form data. I need that in the api controller so I can save the image uploaded. I also need to send a couple of additional parameters though.

Comment: Yes, I'm a moron and misunderstood. Took me a moment to realise that it lives in the "form" part of the httprequest. Propose it as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the parameters by appending them to the url and retrieve them using GET.

For example:

```
uploads/uploadhandler.php?id=89sdkj98f0d8jdfds8&name=newfile.jpg
```

Comment: It's a post, not a get. The answer is in the comments above, the user never got around to posting it as an answer though.